# Automatically turning light on and off use Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As I click On light bulb it turned on and off, Is there any way light bulb turn on and off automatically?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How often should the light turn on/off a second/minute/day/... ?
You have to be a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the set interval function. This will repeatedly call the stated function at a set rate.

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

This specific example I show calls the changeImage function every 1,000 milliseconds, or every second.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
setInterval(changeImage,1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without using the var `timer` you could leave it out. And you should point out what the `1000` stands for.

Comment: Just updated, I thought that he might want to clear the interval at some point.

Comment: Why setInterval(functionName,500) crash browser?

Comment: <script>
        setInterval(one,500);
        function one () {
         document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor= "red";
         
        }
        
        function back () {
         document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor= "black";
         
        }
        </script>
        This is my New Script

Comment: You need to put setInterval after you defined function one.